# Listen for a checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have found several posts with "answers" to this but none of them are working for me.  Why is something that should be so easy so difficult?

All I want is to do something in response to someone checking/unchecking a column of checkboxes.  One solution works most of the time, but sometimes the events aren't fired.  The one I have seen in several places suggests something like this:

```
 private void dgv1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (dgv1.IsCurrentCellDirty) {
            dgv1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
}
private void dgv1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    // Do whatever I want to do.
}
```

Unfortunately the CellValueChanged simply isn't getting called.
I have checked and double checked that both listeners are added:

```
dgv1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv1_CellValueChanged);
dgv1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dgv1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
```

I added print statements to both methodsto verify that theCellValueChanged method is never getting called although the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged one is.  What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I am using a DataTable with this DataGridView.  Would I be better off listening to that?  Does the change occur in the DataTable before I leave the cell?

Comment: Merely checking/unchecking the box won't fire the CellValueChanged event. I think the checkbox in question has to lose focus first. You might take a look at the detail at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

Comment: @David That is the reason for the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event--see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try. But this time in [`CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case 0: //Where the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Index
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = 
                !(bool) dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
            if ((bool)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value)
            {
                //Something to do
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Option: you can set the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` properties to `readonly = true`.

Comment: The readonly part is not optional.  If readonly==false it works about 90% of the time. About 10% of the time the event does not register even though the value changes.  I have only noticed it happening when unchecking a box, but can't confirm that it doesn't happen when checking.  With readonly==true it seems to be reliable.  This makes sense because the value can only change when this code executes, so it either fires an event and changes or doesn't and it doesn't change.  It is a little clunky (if you click twice too rapidly, the second click doesn't register), but it works.

Comment: To clarify, this solution works by itself--WITHOUT the other listeners.  And `ReadOnly` HAS to be set to true for it to be 100% reliable.

Comment: I'm glad that it helps you a bit, you could `upvote` my answer then `:)`

Comment: Sorry, I noticed one more problem.  My cells start out null, so this code crashes.  I actually add the following as the first statement of `case 0`: `if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null || dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.GetType()==typeof(DBNull)) dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = false;`  The check for `null` may be unnecessary since the values seem to default to a `DBNull` object.

Answer (score 0):

My working implementation also uses that approach, but it's slightly different:

```
private void table_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Because I want to respond immediately to the user changing the state of one of the "excluded" cells,
    // I have to detect the dirty state of such a cell changing, then call CommitEdit() in order to explicitly
    // cause the CellValueChanged() event to be raised.

    if (_table.CurrentCellAddress.X == _colExcluded.DisplayIndex)
    {
        _table.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

In this case, `_colExcluded.DisplayIndex` happens to be how I check if the correct column was being clicked.

A difference from your code is that I'm not checking if the current cell is dirty before calling `CommitEdit()`. I think that may be the issue.

Comment: I've taken out all of the code trying to determine if it is the proper column for now.  I'll deal with that once I can get the listeners to actually work at all.  Regarding what to call CommitEdit on, every example I have seen seems to call it on the DataGridView object.

Comment: @ferzle Yep, `_table` in my code is the DataGridView object. I removed my comment about it when I realised it was the same as what you were doing.